# Creando una función para calcular media en R me arroja "argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA"

Tags: r, rstudio

Estoy tratando de crear una función que enlace distintos data frames y luego calcule la media de una columna en particular. Mi función y los datos son los siguientes:

```
data_url<-"https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/rprog%2Fdata%2Fspecdata.zip"
download.file(data_url,"specdata.zip")
unzip("specdata.zip",exdir = "specdata")

specdata<-getwd()
pollutantmean<-function(directory,pollutant,id=1:332){
        files_list<-list.files(directory,full.names = TRUE)
        dat<-data.frame()
        for (i in id) {
                dat<-rbind(dat,read.csv(files_list[i]))
                }
        dat_subset<-dat$pollutant
        mean(dat_subset,na.rm = TRUE)
        }
```

Cuando trato de correr la función no hay problemas pero cuando trato de implementarla me arroja el siguiente error:

```
pollutantmean(specdata,"nitrate",1:10)
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(dat_subset, na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Sin embargo, cuando pruebo cada parte del código por separado me arroja el resultado correcto.
¿Qué puede estar mal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te hago algunas observaciones

```
data_url<-"https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/rprog%2Fdata%2Fspecdata.zip"
download.file(data_url,"specdata.zip")
unzip("specdata.zip")
```

El zip ya viene con los archivos dentro del folder `specdata` por lo que no es necesario indicarlo, a menos que busques que los mismos terminen en una carpeta `specdata/specdata`

En la función, el principal problema es este:

```
dat_subset <- dat$pollutant
```

buscas que `pollutant` sea el nombre de la variable que pasas por parámetro, pero a menos que implementes algo de evaluación no estándar, lo que estas intentando en realidad es extraer la variable `pollutant` que no existe, en todo caso, deberías hacer algo así:

```
dat_subset <- dat[ , pollutant]
```

Finalmente, te quedaría algo así:

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id=1:332) {
        files_list <- list.files(directory,full.names = TRUE)
        dat <- data.frame()
        for (i in id) {
                dat<-rbind(dat,read.csv(files_list[i]))
        }
        mean(dat[, pollutant],na.rm = TRUE)
}

> pollutantmean("specdata","nitrate")
[1] 1.702932
> pollutantmean("specdata","sulfate")
[1] 3.189369
```

Y si eventualmente, siempre lees todos los archivos, podrías  evitarte tener que pasar el vector `id` y simplificar  bastante el código:

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant) {
        files_list <- list.files(directory, pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE)
        dat <- do.call(rbind, lapply(files_list, read.csv))
        mean(dat[, pollutant], na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me ayudó mucho tu respuesta! Saludos